# Send user defined packet through a specified interface in python

Tags: python, sockets, ethernet

I have four ethernet cards installed on my host and I want to send a user defined packet (something on top of ethernet etc.) in python. is there any solution to it?

I have managed to do this in C as following codes:

```
if ((sk = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_USER))) < 0) {
    perror("create socket error\n");
    return -1;
}

// bind the interface like "eth0"
memset(&nsa_ifr, 0, sizeof(nsa_ifr));
strncpy(nsa_ifr.ifr_name, dev_name, sizeof(nsa_ifr.ifr_name));
if (ioctl(sk, SIOCGIFINDEX, &nsa_ifr) < 0) {
    perror("SIOCGIFINDEX error\n");
    return -1;
}

memset(&nsa_dst, 0, sizeof(nsa_dst));
nsa_dst.sll_family   = AF_PACKET;
nsa_dst.sll_ifindex  = nsa_ifr.ifr_ifindex;
nsa_dst.sll_halen    = ETH_ALEN;
nsa_dst.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_USER);

// Then I can send a user defined packet 
n_send = sendto(sk, buf, size, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &nsa_dst, sizeof(nsa_dst));
```

I can do the socket creation the same in python

```
    sk = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs(0x0801))
```

but I have no idea how to bind the socket to a named network interface in python,
 any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean "I failed to bind the socket to a named network interface"? What was the precise failure mode? Did it sent the packet on the wrong interface? Did you receive an error message? Please include the failing Python code in your post.

Comment: sorry for misleading words, "failed" here means I have no idea how to bind a socket to a specified network interface.